# [Rust: UnixDatagram socket]: Address already in use Unix datagram socket

Tags: sockets, rust

I am trying to create simple client server code with unix datagram socket in rust. I am having issue with server keeps address in use even after closing out the terminal so it never binds again with socket file. What is the best way to close the socket and create new one upon start?

here is the sample code

```
use std::fs::{File, read_to_string};
use std::fs;
use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::net::Shutdown;

fn unlink_socket (path: impl AsRef<Path>) {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    if Path::new(path).exists() {
        std::fs::remove_file(path);
    }
}

fn tcp_datagram_server() {
    const FILE_PATH: &str = "/tmp/test.sock";
    let socket;
    let mut buf = vec![0; 4096];
    unlink_socket(FILE_PATH);
    File::create(FILE_PATH).expect("Unable to create file");
    socket = match UnixDatagram::bind(FILE_PATH) {
        Ok(socket) => socket,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't bind: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    println!("Waiting for client to connect...");
    loop {
        let data = socket.recv(buf.as_mut_slice()).expect("recv function failed");
        println!("Received {:?}", data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    tcp_datagram_server();
}
```

Comment: Did the `std::fs::remove_file()` call succeed?

Comment: Remove the call to `File::create`. In fact I'm surprised when you say your code works the first time: it doesn't for me…

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change it completely once it has been answered. [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.